# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.models.embedding.gen_word2vec' has no attribute 'skipgram_word2vec'

Tags: python, error-handling, machine-learning, tensorflow, word2vec

I am new to Tensorflow and I am running the tutorial of word2vec embedding code (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/embedding) on Tensorflow (cpu-only), OS X: 10.11.6. I installed tensorflow via `pip install`.

Running `word2vec_basic.py` can reach the expected result, but when it turns to `word2vec.py` and `word2vec_optimized.py`, the following error is displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [bazel](https://www.bazel.io/) to build the directory, since the op 'skipgram_word2vec' is defined in C++ and not in Python.

Comment: I am having the same error. How do i use bazel.Can i use it in linux.

Comment: Actually, I started looking into this more, and it appears that there's no easy way to get bazel to build the directory. I'm working on a pull request that should let you run word2vec if you compile the ops on your own: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/802

Comment: How can i build the ops for word2vec I can't make out the head or tail of the tensorflow tutorial.

Comment: @Aniruddh: check out the README here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/embedding

Comment: thanks for replying after i ran the word2vec_optimised.py with word2vec_ops.cc i got this error  ....  tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/aniruddh/Desktop/Tensorflow/Vector representation of words/word2vec_ops.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Right, you need to compile the ops as explained in the README so that word2vec_ops.so will be created. Right now I think this will only work on Linux however.