# TensorFlow : How and where to specify save path in word2vec?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, word2vec

I am trying to implementing word2vec model of tensorflow and went through the tutorial of tensorflows [Vector representation of words](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec/#scaling_up_with_noise-contrastive_training).

After that I compiled the [word2vec code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py) in my system and I am getting this output.

```
--train_data --eval_data and --save_path must be specified.
```

I am new to TensorFlow and I don't know where and how should I specify `train_data`, `eval_data` and `save_path`.

Also is there a more detailed tutorial available on TensorFlow vector representation of words to understand the `word2vec` model better.

Comment: You forgot the flags while running the script, see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the script, you need to provide these as flags. Try running it like this,

```
python word2vec.py --train_data <path to training data> --eval_data <path to eval> --save_path <save directory>
```

Comment: when i run it like that its shows this error
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: What exactly did you run?

Comment: like this ..... python word2vec.py --train_data <Trained_Data> --eval_data <Eval_datal> --save_path <Saved_data>

Comment: Yes I added /Desktop/Tensorklow/Saved_data as the path is that the correct way.

Comment: Have you edited the code in anyway? Which line number are you getting the error on?

Comment: No i have not made any changes to the code . That error is the only thing  being shown.I am using Ubuntu by the and I am running this in terminal.

Comment: Could you show me a screenshot of your terminal with the command and the error?

Comment: I have the screen shot how do i send it to u

Comment: Remove `<` and `>` everywhere from your command. If it doesn't work (after your own attempt at debugging), re-send a screenshot

Comment: You should work a bit on your linux skills. Replace `/home/Desktop` with `~/Desktop`. `~` is located in `/home/aniruddh/`

Comment: Yes it needs to be improved  been 4 months since i started using linux still not got complete hang of it

Comment: It helped a lot thanks now I am waiting for this question to be answered.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229308/tensorflow-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-skipgram-word2vec